# Como populo um $scope (angular) com get.Json (jquery)?

Tags: php, ajax, json, angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação PHP e utilizo `$.getJSON` do jQuery para buscar dados e assim apresentá-los ao meu usuário.
Gostaria de preencher uma tabela utilizando Angular.
Como faço para preencher um `$scope` com a resposta do `$.getJSON` ?

Exemplo de código abaixo ( sem a parte da tabela )

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#formulario").submit(function(){
            $.getJSON('arquivo.php', function(retorno){
                //quero pegar esse retorno e jogar no $scope do angular que esta abaixo e assim,
                // deixar o angular popular minha tabela
                        }); 
        });
    });
    });

  // angular --- Aqui abaixo estou preenchendo a minha tabela com os dados abaixo...
  // neste caso estão manual. Quero que os dados abaixo sejam dinamicos.. vindo da tabela.
  // Imagino que esse não deve ser o jeito certo de fazer isso, todavia não sei como faze-lo.
  var ctrlLog = function($scope){
        $scope.loggers = [
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
        ];
  };

</script> 
</code>
```

Comment: Seria mais indicado que você poste um trecho de código de até onde já chegou, tendo em vista que o foco do grupo são dúvidas específicas de programação

Answer (score 3):

Com o Angular, não impedindo que haja outras formas, você deixa de trabalhar com `$.getJSON` e passa a usar as próprias funções dele, como o `$http`:

```html
<table>
    <tr> <!-- Cabeçalho -->
        <th>X</th>
        <th>Y</th>
        <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Dados da tabela: -->
    <tr ng-repeat="coordenda in dados">
        <td>{{coordenada.x}}</td>
        <td>{{coordenada.y}}</td>
        <td>{{coordenada.z}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
  $http({
    method: 'GET', // ou 'POST'
    url: urlDoSeuJSON
  }).success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.dados = data;
  });
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/) (não é meu) | [Exemplo baseado nos dados do autor da pergunta](http://jsfiddle.net/Gc3HN/).

O [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) é um [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services) do AngularJS. Eles ajudam na organização do código pois abstraem funções comuns para os aplicativos web, simplificando o desenvolvimento deles.

Answer (score 1):

O mais recomendável é fazer como o Gustavo falou... ir usando as próprias funções do AngularJS.

Mas no caso teu código, a solução mais simples é colocar a função num local onde ela tenha acesso ao `$scope`. Assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ctrlLog = function($scope){
        $scope.loggers = [
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
            {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
        ];
        $("#formulario").submit(function(){
            $.getJSON('arquivo.php', function(retorno){
                // pronto! aqui o teu código tem acesso direto à variável $scope
            });
        });
  };
</script>
```

---

**Observação**: isso está longe de ser o ideal! Algo mais apropriado seria definir um *service* para comunicar com o servidor usando `$http`, injetá-lo no *controller*, e utilizá-lo para atualizar qualquer propriedade de `$scope` passando-o como parâmetro:

```
var ctrlLog = function($scope, $myService){
    $scope.loggers = [
        {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
        {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
        {nome_controller:'login',nome_action:'logar'},
    ];
    $scope.submitHandler = function() {
        $myService.updateLoggers($scope);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um $resource do Angular para fazer as requisições  e adicione esse $resource em um service.

```
    var services = angular.module('services', ['ngResource']);
    services.factory(
        'Modelo-a-ser-requisitado',
        ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
                return $resource('/api/modelo/:controller:modeloId', {modeloId: '@modeloId', controller: '@controller'},
            {
                pesquisa: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        modeloId: '@modeloId'
                    },
                    isArray: true
                }
            }]);
```

Sendo que o $resource já vem com os metodos ($get, $list e $save) implicitos, bastando chamar.

Para embutir no codigo basta popular o objeto no escopo

```
    Controllers.controller('Ctrl',
    ['$scope', 'Recurso',
    function ($scope, Recurso) {
        $scope.variavel = Recurso.pesquisa({modeloId: 1}, function () {
            //função de callback, puramente opcional
        });
```